# Extract data from a promise Object or Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

> I have an API that returns json. The json has 100 objects, each having
>   image url and description of the image. I use ng-repeat to show the
>   images and modal attached that pops-up when I click the images with
>   its description.

I have 2 templates and 2 controllers for the normal and modal components. I already have images on my HTML and I just need to pass the same data returned from the factory into the ModalInstanceController so that I can show description on image-click.

> Do I need to call the factory method to get the data inside the
>   ModalInstanceController or pass the data from controller (which is an
>   array that contains promise with resolve). The issue is I passed the
>   ietms with resolve but can't extract it inside ModalInstanceController as
>   it's an array containing promise (in console it says 'value was evaluated just now' and I can't use .then() to an array.

My code structure is :

**JSON Factory**

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('Brastlewark')
    .factory('GnomeFactory', GnomeFactory)

  function GnomeFactory($http) {
    let allGnomes = { getAllGnomes }

    function getAllGnomes() {
      const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rrafols/mobile_test/master/data.json'
      return $http.get(url)
        .then(response => response.data.Brastlewark)
    }
    return allGnomes
  }
})()
```

**Main Controller that opens modal-instance**

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('Brastlewark')
    .controller('DetailsController', DetailsController)

  function DetailsController(GnomeFactory, $log, $uibModal) {
    let vm = this

    GnomeFactory.getAllGnomes()
      .then((data) => {
        vm.gnomeList = data
        return vm.gnomeList
      })

    // opening modal window to trigger model instance controller to act
    vm.showModal = (index) => {
      $log.log(`Button with index ${index} was clicked !!`)
      let configModal = {
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
        size: 'sm',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        resolve: {
          gnomeData: () => vm.gnomeList
        }
      }
      let modalInstance = $uibModal.open(configModal)
      modalInstance.result.then(console.log, console.log)
    }
  }
})()
```

**ModalController**

```
angular
  .module('Brastlewark')
  .controller('ModalController', ModalController)

function ModalController($scope, $uibModalInstance, $log, gnomeData) {

  $scope.gnomeList = gnomeData
  $scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope)
  }
  $scope.cancel = () => {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel')
  }
}
```

**Template for both**

```
    <section id="details">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="gnome in vm.gnomeList">
          <button type="button" ng-click="vm.showModal($index)">
            <img ng-src={{gnome.thumbnail}}>
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <!-- @modal template start -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal.html">
      <div class="modal-body" id="modalbody">
        <ul>
          <p>Friends : </p>
          <li ng-repeat="friend in gnomeList.friends">
            <span>{{friend}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

NOTE: IT SHOWS MODAL AND INDEX OF IMAGE CLICKED... But doesn't receive the array.

Comment: yes it is object, have you tried calling `.then` method of it. or try to add code here

Comment: just make `api` call in service and return, handle the response using `then` in controller.

Comment: yes when i pass the array via resolve (from main controller to the modalInstance controller), it says allImages.then() is not a function..

Comment: Can you please provide your promise call and promise callback code

Comment: pls paste your service code, and controller's handing of promise.

Comment: Who are you quoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your service to,** (returning only API promise)

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('Brastlewark')
    .factory('GnomeFactory', GnomeFactory)

  function GnomeFactory($http) {
    let allGnomes = { getAllGnomes }

    function getAllGnomes() {
      const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rrafols/mobile_test/master/data.json'
      return $http.get(url)
    }
    return allGnomes
  }
})()
```

**returning just an API promise `return $http.get(url)`**

**Now your controller, handle the promise returned from the service using `then`**

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('Brastlewark')
    .controller('DetailsController', DetailsController)

  function DetailsController(GnomeFactory, $log, $uibModal) {
    let vm = this

    GnomeFactory.getAllGnomes()
      .then((data) => {
        vm.gnomeList = data.data.Brastlewark
        return vm.gnomeList
      },(data) => {
       console.log('error')
      })

    // opening modal window to trigger model instance controller to act
    vm.showModal = (index) => {
      $log.log(`Button with index ${index} was clicked !!`)
      let configModal = {
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
        size: 'sm',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        resolve: {
          gnomeData: () => vm.gnomeList
        }
      }
      let modalInstance = $uibModal.open(configModal)
      modalInstance.result.then(console.log, console.log)
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: @Jamie, pls check the changes you have to make from this answer.

Comment: Hi Sravan. thanks for the effort. I made the changes but it's still the same. I have the images on my DOM, when I click them it opens modal window as expected along with the index of the element clicked.

Comment: The issue is that the modal shows no friendlist (ie can't ng-repeat the data passed using resolve)

Comment: in your `modal` controller, `console.log(gnomeData)` and check what is coming

Comment: It returns the same array I used to populate images on DOM . But I'm unable to populate it in the same way. Should I ng-repeat the 'gnomeData' in the modal template or the original vm.gnomeList? (none working btw)

Comment: In your modal template,  `<p>{{gnomeList}} </p>` and check whats coming in template

Comment: gnomeData does show 1300 elements in the modal window :)  Now I somehow need to find out how to show only the data for the clicked item

Comment: jquery based modal doesn't require anything. it's plug and play comparing this -.-

Comment: I suppose I need to insert the modal-template inside the ng-repeat so the image and modal window are related. right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139374/discussion-between-sravan-and-jamie).